# How to allow guest to access home page without login in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

This has to be super simple, but I can't quite figure it out.

I want guest users (not logged in) to be allowed to go to the home page and not be redirected to the login page.

what is the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delete the middleware,
it could be in the routes file or in your Controller like this

routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['admin']], function(){
//Your routes
});
```

Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: Found it in my homepage controller.

Comment: I am getting 419  page expired error after removing middleware in route. any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Usually for authentification some middleware is used, so if you want the homepage to be accessible for unauthorized users you should remove auth middleware from homepage route.